# What is a predual of the Banach space of compact operators on $\ell^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I am wondering if the space $K(\ell^2)$ of compact operators on $\ell^2$ can have a predual.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: This question arises from the fact that the dual of K(l^2) is the trace class C_1 which is analogous to the fact that the dual of c_0 is l_1. It is well known that c_0 has no predual.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: In [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01344152) paper, it's shown $K(\ell_2)$ is not even isomorphic to a dual of a Banach space.

Comment: Thank you very much David. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an operator theorist's argument.

Assume $K(\ell_2)$ is a dual Banach space. Since $K(\ell_2)$ is a $C^*$-algebra, by Sakai's theorem we have that $K(\ell_2)$ is a von Neumann algebra. Take any $a\in K(\ell_2)$ with infinite dimensional image. Since $K(\ell_2)$ is a von Neumann algebra then there exists an orthogonal projection $p\in K(\ell_2)$ on $\operatorname{Im}(a)$. So $\operatorname{Im}(p)$ is infinite dimensional, which is impossible because $p$ is compact. Contradisction, so $K(\ell_2)$ is not a dual space.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is the gist of the argument given in the [linked paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01344152) in my comment above:

In said paper it is shown that if $H$ is a separable Hilbert space, then $K(H)$ is separable  (look at finite-rank operators) and that $K(H)$ contains in isomorphic copy of $c_0$ (fix an orthonormal basis and look at the multiplication operators induced by elements of $c_0$).

$c_0$, however, does not embed in a separable dual space. See, e.g.,   Kalton and
 Albiac, *Topics in Banach Space Theory*, [Theorem 6.3.7](http://books.google.com/books?id=FkjCulO5xg0C&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=c_0+does+not+embed+in+separable+dual&source=bl&ots=ZrMMBXagR9&sig=-TPdL0EDZIcvsMsMKLhLyixdSlQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PVqnU6v6GJSpsQSVpoGACQ&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=c_0%20does%20not%20embed%20in%20separable%20dual&f=false).

From this, it follows that $K(H)$ is not isomorphic to a dual space if $H$ is separable (in fact, it's not isomorphic to any subspace of a separable dual space).

Comment: Thank you very much again David.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give an alternative approach.

Separable dual spaces have the Radon–Nikodym property. The algebra of compact operators on a separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is of course separable. The closed unit ball of a space with the Radon–Nikodym property is the closed convex hull of its extreme points (using a fancy language: Radon–Nikodym property implies the Krein–Milman property).

But wait... [an extreme point in the closed unit ball of a C*-algebra must be a partial isometry](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gtnMW_uH7DcC&lpg=PA306&dq=extreme%20point%20unitary%20C%2a-algebra&hl=pl&pg=PA306#v=onepage&q=54.2&f=false), so in particular the underlying C*-algebra must have a projection with infinite-dimensional range, which is not the case for $\mathscr{K}(H)$ – there are, thus, no extreme points in the ball of the compacts at all.